# Cdk python code to create rds aurora serverless_v2 cluster

Tags: python, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-aurora-serverless

cdk --version : 2.62.2
python3 --version : Python 3.9.10

How to create AWS RDS-Aurora (PostgreSQL Compatible) with DB instance class as Serverless_v2  resource with multiple read instance using CDK python. I couldn't find proper documentation for the same, someone please help me in figuring out the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please add your CDK code to the question.